# WooCommerce - Is it possible to add a role to a not logged in visitor?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using B2B for Woocommerce plugin to set different prices for different user roles.
Is it possible for WordPress to set a particular user role for each visitor who is not logged in, so that he could see different prices than registered users who have user roles?

I'm aware that user roles in WordPress are set upon registration, but is it possible to assign a role to a non-registered user, who just visits the website?

I was trying to write a snippet, but I suck in PHP. That's what I came up with

```
function set_custom_role_to_visitors() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() == false } {
            $user->set_role('guest');
        }
}
```

Obviously it didn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: a visitor who is not logged in is not a user - see doc (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/ ):  "The current user will be set to the logged-in person. ". So why not show different prices depending on is_user_logged_in() ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, the B2B for Woocommerce plugin seems to create a Guest user role for visitors. I did some digging and the problem concerns only variable products (simple products work correctly). The plugin itself must be bugged, so I contacted support to address the issue asap. Hopefully it will be corrected with the next update.